# put a running program into background like screen

Tags: gnu-screen

There is a program that takes unexpectedly long to run. Before I started it, I did not start `screen`. So I dont know how to detach the process now. Is there any way to keep this process running on background even if I quit the current ssh session without killing it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is with `CTRL-z` to suspend the process, and then `bg` to resume it in the background. Once running as a background process, you can disconnect and it will keep running.

If you need to reattach the process to a terminal later, you can use `reptyr`, which should be in your distributions repositories.

Comment: Under `bg`, will the process get killed when the ssh session close?

Comment: No, it will keep running in the background. If you disconnect and reconnect you'll be able to see it in the process list.

Answer (score 0):

`disown` should prevent the shell from sending it a `HUP` or such on exit of the shell.